# Firefox cookies: How to read "Expires: At end of session" type cookies

Tags: firefox, cookies

I am able to read the cookies from the sqlite db in firefox.
However, I need to also read the cookies that are marked "Expires: At end of session" in the firefox cookie list.

It appears that these are NOT stored in the sqlite database.

Is there any means to read these programmatically?

Thanks,
Elijah

Answer (score 5):

I also want to do this and can't figure it out.  They must be stored somewhere, since they are there if you recover a Firefox session.  Closest thing I've found is:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/66579

which allows you to export them.  But no dice programmatically.

Edit:
Actually I figured it out.  They are stored in 'sessionstore.js' as javascript in your firefox profile.  A python example is:

```
true = True
false = False
s = eval(file('<path to firefox profile>/sessionstore.js').read())
s['windows'][0]['cookies']
```

Comment: Hmm good pdf about this: http://computerforensics.parsonage.co.uk/downloads/WebBrowserSessionRestoreForensics.pdf